# NestedScrollView incomplete scroll

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm using NestedScrollView in order to reach something [similar to this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout).

[image]

## Update

This is my [repo](https://github.com/rcAndroidTutorials/Material-design-Animations).

I figure out when the mobile turns to landscape the scroll don't let me visualize the buttons or **the grey view at bottom**.

This is my `mainlayout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_tipo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/aviso_128dp"/>

            <!--<include layout="@layout/toolbar_pin" />-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/field_nombre"
                        layout="@layout/actividad_field" />

                    <include layout="@layout/actividad_separator" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/field_direccion"
                        layout="@layout/actividad_field" />

                    <include layout="@layout/actividad_separator" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/field_direccion2"
                        layout="@layout/actividad_field" />

                    <include layout="@layout/actividad_separator" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/field_localidad"
                        layout="@layout/actividad_field" />

                    <include layout="@layout/actividad_separator" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/field_provincia"
                        layout="@layout/actividad_field" />

                    <include layout="@layout/actividad_separator" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/field_telefono"
                        layout="@layout/actividad_field" />

                    <include layout="@layout/actividad_separator" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/field_email"
                        layout="@layout/actividad_field" />

                    <include layout="@layout/actividad_separator" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/field_descripcion"
                        layout="@layout/actividad_field" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_productos"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ver productos" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_finalizar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Finalizar" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@color/gray"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the `actividad_separator.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/divider"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the `actividad_field.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_primary_36dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_clave"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="Clave" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_valor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Valor"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how looks like:

[image]
[image]

This is how it works (incomplete scrolling because I cant see the grey bar at the bottom):

[image]

Comment: try adding some space at the bottom of your scroll,I've had a simlar problem

Comment: That's why i added the gray bar. When I run the project i can't see the gray bar.

Comment: What's the problem actually? You want to show the buttons at the bottom of your layout completely, right? That's the question you are asking? Please clarify.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I wrote `incomplete scrolling because I cant see the grey bar at the bottom`. If you run the project(my repo is in the post) you can see how the scroll is not showing all subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `NestedScrollView` add `android:paddingBottom="50dp"`

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:paddingBottom="50dp"
     android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `NestedScrollView` you have a vertical `LinearLayout`. 
You need to change its height to `wrap_content`.

Comment: I tried but is still failing. Throughout today I will try to upload a dummy project in order to show this problem in a clear way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem replacing linear layout with constraintlayout and adding bottom constraint to bottom of that scrollview and adding some margin to it worked for me. You can try that.

Comment: I will consider it. But i wouldn't like to deal with constraintlayout yet.

Comment: try adding translationZ to the whole layout

Comment: <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center" android:translationZ="10dp">                                            Just add the last line and check, if this doesn't work try adding it at the bottom view, i guess it might help

Comment: That's interesting, have tried a adding a dummyview at the bottom, if not add a view with height of 2-3 dp and place it beneath your bottom most view inside scrollview

Answer (score 0):

After doing all the layout changes I made a little change in Manifest added android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in activity and worked perfectly in landscape

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>  



[![Landscape Image][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LHpR.png
```

Comment: If you test in portrait(without change mobile orientation) the grey bar is still missing.